# Deleting a redundant parameter results in a segmentation fault, seemingly for no reason

Tags: c

The following program finds and deletes words that begin and end with the same character. It works just fine, except I decided to take the code for printing result text in from `deleteWords()` and put it inside of `main()`. Therefore, the `*fpOut` parameter in became redundant in `deleteWords()`. Deleting the parameter results in

`/bin/sh: line 1:  1371 Segmentation fault: 11  ./main duom.txt rez.txt make: *** [main] Error 139`

However if I compile it and run it any third parameter (e.g. `int useless` argument instead of `FILE *fpOut`), it works without errors.

Has anybody have a clue what could be causing this problem?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int checker (char zodis[]) {
        size_t last = strlen(zodis);
        if (zodis[0] == zodis[last-1])
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }

    void memAlloc (char **text, char **buffer, FILE **fp, char *fileName) {
        int fileLength;
        *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
        fseek(*fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
        fileLength = fseek(*fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
        *text = malloc(fileLength * sizeof(char));
        *buffer = malloc(fileLength * sizeof(char));
    }

    void deleteWords (FILE *fp, int anyUselessParameter, char *buffer) {
        char *text;
        while (fscanf(fp, "%s", text) == 1) {
            if (checker(text)) {
                printf("%s ", text);
                sprintf(buffer + strlen(buffer), "%s ", text);
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        FILE *fp, *fpOut;
        int anyUselessParameter;
        char *text, *buffer, *inputFileName = argv[1], *outputFileName = argv[2];

        if (argc < 2)
            return 0;

        fpOut = fopen(outputFileName, "w");

        memAlloc(&text, &buffer, &fp, inputFileName);
        deleteWords(fp, anyUselessParameter, buffer);
        fputs(buffer, fpOut);

        fclose(fp);
        fclose(fpOut);
        free(text);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined. Anything could happen. For exmple, what is this `sprintf(buffer + strlen(buffer), "%s ", text);` supposed to do?

Comment: `text` is not allocated in `deleteWords`

Comment: @NeilButterworth It will mostly act like a strcat ? no ?

Comment: @Tom buffer+strlen(buffer) is a pointer to the null terminator at the end of buffer, or would be, if buffer were null-terminated correctly. sprintf applied to that pointer will overwrite memory that is not part of buffer.

Answer (score 4):

```
char *text;
while (fscanf(fp, "%s", text) == 1) {
```

`scanf` needs the buffer to be allocated. Here it dereferences an uninitialized pointer `text` and writes to it. `scanf` tries to write to `text[0]`, `text[1]`.. and so on, so accesses text out of bounds and undefined behavior happen.

```
*buffer = malloc(fileLength * sizeof(char));
...
sprintf(buffer + strlen(buffer), "%s ", text);
```

`buffer` is uninitialized, so `strlen(buffer)` will result in some undefined value. Explicitly initialize `buffer[0] = '\0'` if you wish to use strlen later. Also you don't include memory for terminating `'\0'` character inside your buffer.

As you are trying to read the file into a buffer, that is allocated using the file size

```
if (fread(buffer, fileLenght, 1, fp) != fileLength) { /* handle error */ }
```

If you have to, use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` just to be safe. `snprinttf(buffer+strlen(buffer), fileLength - strlen(buffer), ...);`

Also, try to never use `scanf` without specifing field length inside `%s` modifier. You can try:

```
char text[256]; // or other maximum word length
while (fscanf(fp, "%255s", text) == 1) {
```

As you already have allocated memory for the file, you can use it as a parameter to scanf, if you have to. One would need to prepare the format string for scanf as argument - it is a bit hard. See below:

```
 for (;;) {
      // prepare scanf %s format modifier to use with printf to write to buffer end
      char fmt[20];
      size_t buffer_size = fileLenght;
      size_t free_in_buffer = buffer_size - strlen(buffer);
      snprintf(fmt, 20, "%%%ds", free_in_buffer);
      // we will write here: up to free_in_buffer
      char *in = buffer + strlen(buffer);
      if (fscanf(fp, fmt, in) != 1) break;
      // we now check the last readed word form the file
      if (!checker(in)) { 
         // if the last readed word is bad, we can revert it
         in[0] = '\0'
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way, I found that the main reason why the code didn't work as I intended was that I allocated memory for `*text` in `memAlloc()` and then forgot to pass that pointer with allocated memory into `deleteWords`.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
fileLength = fseek(*fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
```

Per [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseek.html):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> The `fseek()` and `fseeko()` functions shall return 0 if they
>   succeed.
>
> Otherwise, they shall return -1 and set errno to indicate the error.

Comment: You're right. I meant to write:

        *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
        fseek(*fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
        fileLength = (int) ftell(*fp);
        fseek(*fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);